# Openam - Unable to get Application SSO Token

Tags: single-sign-on, openam

I am trying to bring up my tomcat server on which OpenAM is installed but the server fails on startup because the Policy Agent installed on the same server is trying to access a naming service on the same server.

I am just in the middle of a proof of concept and I am following the instructions given by ForgeRock documentation but I am unable to get this setup working.

Is there a way to run the OpenAM+Policy Agent on the same server? Any help in this would be really really appreciated! Thanks!

```
com.sun.identity.authentication.spi.AuthLoginException: Failed to create    new Authentication Context: Naming Service is not available

SEVERE: Begin event threw error java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.sun.identity.agents.arch.Manager.<clinit>(Manager.java:675)
        at com.sun.identity.agents.tomcat.v6.AmTomcatRealm.<clinit>(AmTomcatRealm.java:67)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:145)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1288)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:648)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1561)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:615)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load configuration: ApplicationSSOTokenProvider.getApplicationSSOToken(): Unable to get Application SSO Token
        at com.sun.identity.agents.arch.AgentConfiguration.bootStrapClientConfiguration(AgentConfiguration.java:790)
        at com.sun.identity.agents.arch.AgentConfiguration.initializeConfiguration(AgentConfiguration.java:1140)
        at com.sun.identity.agents.arch.AgentConfiguration.<clinit>(AgentConfiguration.java:1579)
        ... 29 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [this part](http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam-pa/3.5.0/jee-users-guide/index.html) of the documentation is quite relevant:

> Do not install the Java EE policy agent in the same container as OpenAM. OpenAM must be up and running before the Java EE policy agent starts. This cannot be guaranteed when both run in the same container. ForgeRock does not support configurations where OpenAM and the Java EE policy agent are installed in the same container.